# Numpy cuts zeros at end of a number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

To those of you more familiar with python lists and numpy arrays:
I've noticed that when a python list (of float numbers) is converted into a numpy array, trailing significant zeros are removed. A simple code illustrates that:

```
import numpy as np

# python list
list = [1.20780,4.6340]

# convert to numpy array
arr = np.asfarray(list)

print(arr) 
[ 1.2078  4.634 ]
```

Do you know why numpy cuts out the trailing zeros? Any idea how to force numpy to keep the zeros?

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, 1.2078 is equal to 1.20780.
The print method `print` your array as the type predefined `float64`.

If you want to print on 5 digits, you can convert to string like that :

```
In[24]: print ['%.5f'%i for i in arr]
['1.20780', '4.63400']
```

You can also play with the `dtype` to see the encoding #bits impact on the representation of your figure in memory :

```
In[26]: arr.astype('float16')
Out[26]: array([ 1.20800781,  4.6328125 ], dtype=float16)
In[27]: arr.astype('float32')
Out[27]: array([ 1.20780003,  4.63399982], dtype=float32)
In[28]: arr.astype('float64')
Out[28]: array([ 1.2078,  4.634 ])
In[29]: arr.astype('int')
Out[29]: array([1, 4])
In[30]: arr.astype('int8')
Out[30]: array([1, 4], dtype=int8)
In[31]: arr.astype('float')
Out[31]: array([ 1.2078,  4.634 ])
In[32]: arr.astype('float5')
```

Comment: By the way is it possible to convert a float of 4 decimals 1.2078 to a float with 5 decimals num = 1.20780, so I can do str(num)? Then if I print str(num), I expect to see 1.20780

Comment: @user3578925: As much as I know, it's not possible to extend the number of decimal directly. The only way is the one I given hereover. For knowing more on datatype : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Answer (score 0):

If you print the list from Python, you'll see that the trailing zeroes are also missing:

```
>>> list = [1.20780,4.6340]
>>> list
[1.2078, 4.634]
```

The base reason is that, to the hardware and the run-time system, they are *not* significant.  They do not affect the numeric value of the float.  They do not affect numerical processing, as the hardware does not pay attention to "significant digits", other than the natural precision of the data type, when it does calculations.  There are no error ranges considered.

What effects did you have in mind for the numerical values?

---

I see.  Yes, you can do that ... but keep the original text of the file name.  Once you convert it to the numeric value, the trailing zeros are not recoverable.  You would not be able to differentiate 1.29780 from 1.2978 or 1.297800000000

Even better, sort on the extracted float value, as I've done below.  That one-line command does the following

- Split the name at the hyphens.
- Extract the second item in that split
- Use it as the value on which to sort the item
- Feed this value extraction as the key to the sort function.
- Sort the list.

  file_list = [
      "NEW-2.3087-QA",
      "NEW-16.8888-HX",
      "NEW-1.20780-BC",
      "OLD-9.678900-NO"
      ]

  order_list = sorted(file_list, key=lambda name: float((name.split('-'))[1]))

  print(order_list)

... and the output:

```
["NEW-1.20780-BC", "NEW-2.3087-QA", "OLD-9.678900-NO", "NEW-16.8888-HX"]
```

Does that do what you need?  Will you ever have two files with the same numerical value, but different representations, such as "A-1.0-Z" and "B-1.000-ST" ?

Comment: The reason I want the zeros is that I have a list of len(20000) file names with a sample name: AN-1.20780-BC. I need to extract these numbers from the file names and sort them into ascending order. Then I need to create new files with the sorted numbers e.g.,  NEW-1.20780-BC. Obviously, if during the sorting the zeros are removed I end up with  NEW-1.2078-BC instead of NEW-1.20780-BC.